# Disabling/bypassing Rich Text Editor validation

Tags: rich-text, 2010

I've implemented a custom ribbon button/dialog to insert a link to a document contained in a third party DMS. The DMS client installs a protocol handler that allows the use of links such as the following -

```
iwl:dms=DEV85SERVER&lib=LIVE&num=25210&ver=1
```

Unfortunately, upon saving the page, the above URL is stripped out and I'm left with an empty A tag.

Is it possible to either disable the SP2010 RTE validation, or escape the above URL somehow to prevent the A tag being sanitized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going with an alternative approach. I added an .aspx page to my package, and had the RTE inserted link pass the relevant parameters over to the new page. Then, the .aspx page regenerated the original URL and handled it accordingly.

Comment: There's a waiting period to accept your own answers, I was planning to do so once it has elapsed.

Comment: Fair enough. I jumped the gun obviously. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ContentEditorWebPart`. Your url won't be stripped out. This approach is also used when trying to add javascript to a web page.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately (in this case) there's a requirement to have this functionality available in RTE's outside of web parts.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I wanted to have a hyperlink column using DMS link.

e.g link: iwl:dms=DEV85SERVER&lib=LIVE&num=25210&ver=1

e.g link description: Document test

I tried to create a hyperlink column but SharePoint didn't recognize my DMS link.

So I had to create a calculated column to make the DMS link works.

1. Create a column called "Document Link" as Single line of text.
2. Create another column called "Document Description" as Single line of text.
3. Create a third column called "Link" as a calculated column.

   3.1 insert the following formula:

```html
=IF([Document Link]="","To be inserted","<a href='"&[Document Link]&"'>"&[Document Description]&"</a>")
```

3.2 Change the type returned from this formula to "Number"

Done!

This is just an example. 
I hope it helps.